# Django and Lytebox - posting form data

Tags: javascript, django

I'm trying to display poll results using lytebox but can't work out how to pass either GET/POST variables to the page I'm calling.

Lytebox is working fine as this loads the page ok:

```
<a href="/polls/1/results"  rel="lyteframe" title="Example Poll" rev="width: 400px; height: 450px; scrolling: yes;">Results</a>
```

But I want to get the value of the selected radio buttons for processing.  I tried using a javascript function to include the choice at the end of the url, ie. /polls/1/vote?choice=1 and redirecting:

```
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice1" value="1" />

    <a href="javascript:vote();"  rel="lyteframe" title="Example Poll" rev="width: 400px; height: 450px; scrolling: yes;">Vote</a>
```

But of course, this just loads the results in a new page.  Lytebox doesn't seem to allow for any POST/GET variables? or is it just me?

Comment: Please show the containing form for your `<input>`.  Also, wouldn't you use a `<input type="submit" name="Vote" />` for the vote button?

Answer (score 0):

Because lytebox requirements include the rev and rel attributes to be set in an `<a` tag I couldn't use it to send GET/POST data, I ended up going with jquery (using thickbox's tb_show function) and a AJAX call to send the selected choice to my script and show the results.